# Buscar valores mas populares en array javascript

Tags: javascript

Como puedo modificar esta funcion para que en lugar de mostrarme el valor mas popular me muestre los 3 valores mas populares, con populares me refiero a los valores que mas se repiten en el array.

Funcion

```js
function mode(array)
{
    if(array.length == 0)
        return null;
    var modeMap = {};
    var maxEl = array[0], maxCount = 1;
    for(var i = 0; i < array.length; i++)
    {   
        var el = array[i];
        
        if(modeMap[el] == null){
            modeMap[el] = 1;6
          }else{
            modeMap[el]++;  
          }
        if(modeMap[el] > maxCount)
        { 
            maxEl = el;
            maxCount = modeMap[el];
        }
    }
    return maxEl;
}
```

Ejemplo de array

```
["PHP", "Joomla", "PHP", "PHP", "PHP", "Joomla", "PHP", "PHP", "Joomla", "Wordpress", "PHP", "PHP", "Joomla", "Joomla", "PHP", "Joomla", "PHP", "Joomla", "PHP", "Joomla", "PHP", "PHP", "PHP", "PHP", "PHP", "PHP", "NodeJS", "Joomla", "PHP"]0: "PHP"1: "Joomla"2: "PHP"3: "PHP"4: "PHP"5: "Joomla"6: "PHP"7: "PHP"8: "Joomla"9: "Wordpress"10: "PHP"11: "PHP"12: "Joomla"13: "Joomla"14: "PHP"15: "Joomla"16: "PHP"17: "Joomla"18: "PHP"19: "Joomla"20: "PHP"21: "PHP"22: "PHP"23: "PHP"24: "PHP"25: "PHP"26: "NodeJS"27: "Joomla"28: "PHP"length: 29__proto__: Array[0]
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Como puedo modificar esta función para que en lugar de mostrarme el valor mas popular me muestre los 3 valores más populares

En lugar de modificar tu función voy a proponer una nueva.

Para obtener el resultado que buscas podrías hacer esto:

- Creamos un objeto (`hash`) donde llevaremos la cuenta de la cantidad de veces que aparece el `valor` en el arreglo.
- Con [`.forEach()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/Array/forEach) recorremos el arreglo y en el `hash` la cuenta de las apariciones.
- Luego con [`Object.keys`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys), obtenemos un arreglo con las claves del `hash` y con el método [`.sort`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/Array/sort) ordenamos el arreglo.

De esta forma, obtendrás un `array` con los `valores` ordenados descendentemente según la cantidad de apariciones en el `array` inicial.

Así por ejemplo:

```js
function mode(array) {
  var hash = {};
  // Contamos ocurrencias
  array.forEach(function(value) {
    hash[value] = hash[value] || 0;
    hash[value]++;
  });
  return Object.keys(hash)
    // Ordenamos el hash
    .sort(function(a, b) {
      return hash[b] - hash[a];
    });
}


var array = ["PHP", "Joomla", "PHP", "PHP", "PHP", "Joomla", "PHP", "PHP", "Joomla", "Wordpress", "PHP", "PHP", "Joomla", "Joomla", "PHP", "Joomla", "PHP", "Joomla", "PHP", "Joomla", "PHP", "PHP", "PHP", "PHP", "PHP", "PHP", "NodeJS", "Joomla", "PHP"];
console.log(JSON.stringify(mode(array)));
// Solo los ultimos 3
console.log(JSON.stringify(mode(array).slice(0, 3)));
```

### // UPDATE

Si además necesitarás saber cual el `número de ocurrencias` de cada `valor`, podrías hacerlo así:

- Con [`.reduce()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/Array/reduce) recorremos el arreglo y obtenemos un `array` de `object`, donde cada `object` tiene las propiedades `value` (valor en el `array` inicial) y `count` (cantidad de ocurrencias).

```js
function mode(array) {
  var hash = {};
  return array
    // Contamos ocurrencias
    .reduce(function(result, value) {
      if (hash[value] === undefined) {
        hash[value] = result.length;
        result.push({
          value: value,
          count: 0
        });
      }
      result[hash[value]].count++;
      return result;
    }, [])
    // Ordenamos el hash
    .sort(function(a, b) {
      return b.count - a.count;
    });
}


var array = ["PHP", "Joomla", "PHP", "PHP", "PHP", "Joomla", "PHP", "PHP", "Joomla", "Wordpress", "PHP", "PHP", "Joomla", "Joomla", "PHP", "Joomla", "PHP", "Joomla", "PHP", "Joomla", "PHP", "PHP", "PHP", "PHP", "PHP", "PHP", "NodeJS", "Joomla", "PHP"];
console.log(JSON.stringify(mode(array)));
// Solo los ultimos 3
console.log(JSON.stringify(mode(array).slice(0, 3)));
```

Comment: Se le podría añadir un for para que imprima no solo los tres valores que se repiten , si no también las veces que se repite dicho valor.

Comment: @Dev.Joel en realidad me sirve mas asi como esta, porque es para mostrar las categorias mas usadas en mi sitio ;)

Comment: Para este caso ayuda para lo que desea realizar. Pero a  otro usuario pueda que le interese obtener también la cantidad. Solo es una recomendación.

Comment: @Dev.Joel, he agregado en mi respuesta otra opción para cubrir tu comentario.

Comment: Excelente respuesta